# Navigation Javascript removing the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I use navigation from bootstrap and a little PHP to make it modular. I used jQuery to add an "active" CSS class on the client-side.

I want to add active class to "The Plan" "Nominees" "News" "FAQs" and "Contact" when they are active and don't do anything on "Vote Now" and "The Homepage".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,''));    
    $('#menu_list li a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } 
        // I added this for removing the active class from all the nav items on home page (which is the logo)
        else if (url == ''){
            $('#menu_list li a').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
})
```

And here is my header.php

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav" id="menu_list">
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="the_plan.php">The Plan</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="nominees.php">Nominees</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="news.php">News</a></li>
          <li class="logo_container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/images/point_north_logo.png"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="vote_now.php"><button class="btn_vote">Vote Now!</button></a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The issue is when I'm on the Home page, this code adds active to all the links. What I'm trying to achieve is when I'm Home Page, I don't want to add any classes to other links. The code I found is looking for href to highlight I believe, and if it can't find it. It highlights all of them with adding active class to all.

I don't have JSfiddle for this because since script looking for hyperlinks with a clear destination. fiddle didn't work for some reason. If somebody can help me with this that would be great, however, if you need a staging I can try to set something up.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Bora - you don't really ask a question. What in your code is not working with respect to what you wish to achieve? Do you have a demo page (e.g. codepen or jsfiddle) set up? Please specify this in your question.